server-sent-events(SSE) cannot re-establish the link. net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
I am using springboot to develop the function of server-sent-events push to the browser. When I finish the development, server-sent-events connection can always be established for the first time, but after the establishment is completed, a second connection will be automatically initiated immediately. The second connection always times out, about 30s. And I get net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
Here's my code
@GetMapping(value = "/connect", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public SseEmitter createConnect() {
    // get user id
    return gapRefundService.createConnect(userId);
}

public SseEmitter createConnect(String userId) {
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = sseEmitterCacheUtils.get(userId);
    if (sseEmitter != null) {
        sseEmitterCacheUtils.removeClient(userId);
        return sseEmitterCacheUtils.create(userId, expireTime());
    }
    return sseEmitterCacheUtils.create(userId, expireTime());
}

My SseEmitterCacheUtils is
@Component
public class SseEmitterCacheUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SseEmitterCacheUtils.class);

    private final Map<String, SseEmitter> SSE_CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(128);

    @Resource
    private CacheService cacheService;

    private static final String SSE_LOCK_KEY = "sse_lock_key:";

    private static final long WAITE_TIME = 1L;

    public SseEmitter create(String clientId, Long expireTime) {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(expireTime);
        sseEmitter.onCompletion(completionCallBack(clientId));
        sseEmitter.onTimeout(timeoutCallBack(clientId));
        sseEmitter.onError(errorCallBack(clientId));
        SSE_CACHE.put(clientId, sseEmitter);
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("create sse connect，now user: {}", clientId);
        }
        this.sendConnectSuccess(sseEmitter, clientId);
        return sseEmitter;
    }

    public void sendConnectSuccess(SseEmitter sseEmitter, String clientId) {
        try {
            OutSseMessageDTO outSseMessageDTO = OutSseMessageDTO.builder()
                    .message("connect_success")
                    .build();
            sseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.event().id(IdUtil.getSnowflakeNextIdStr())
                    .data(JsonUtil.toJson(outSseMessageDTO), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("send connect success, clientId:{}", clientId);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("create sse connect exception, clientId:{}, exception:", clientId, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("unknown exception SseEmitterCacheUtils sendConnectSuccess, clientId:{}, exception message:{}", clientId, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public SseEmitter get(String clientId) {
        return SSE_CACHE.get(clientId);
    }

    public Boolean send(String clientId, String msg) {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = SSE_CACHE.get(clientId);
        if (sseEmitter != null) {
            try {
                boolean lockSuccess = cacheService.tryLock(SSE_LOCK_KEY + clientId, WAITE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (!lockSuccess) {
                    throw ExceptionFactory.bizNoStackException("sse message: another machine locked, skip execute");
                }
                return sendMessage(sseEmitter, msg, clientId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("unknown exception SseEmitterCacheUtils send, exception is:", e);
            } finally {
                cacheService.unlock(SSE_LOCK_KEY + clientId);
            }
        }
        throw ExceptionFactory.bizNoStackException("now sseEmitter is null, may connect already timeout");
    }

    private Boolean sendMessage(SseEmitter sseEmitter, String msg, String clientId) {
        try {
            sseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.event().id(IdUtil.getSnowflakeNextIdStr())
                    .data(msg, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("send sse connect exception, clientId:{}, exception:", clientId, e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Runnable completionCallBack(String clientId) {
        return () -> {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("complete connect: {}", clientId);
            }
            removeClient(clientId);
        };
    }

    private Runnable timeoutCallBack(String clientId) {
        return () -> {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("connect timeout: {}", clientId);
            }
            removeClient(clientId);
        };
    }

    private Consumer<Throwable> errorCallBack(String clientId) {
        return throwable -> {
            LOGGER.info("SseEmitterCacheUtils#errorCallBack, connect error, clientId:{}, exception:", clientId, throwable);
            removeClient(clientId);
        };
    }

    public void removeClient(String clientId) {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = this.get(clientId);
        if (sseEmitter != null) {
            sseEmitter.complete();
            SSE_CACHE.remove(clientId);
        }
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("SseEmitterCacheUtils#removeUser, removeUser: {}", clientId);
        }
    }
}

I set the timeout period of SseEmitter to 5 minutes
I don't understand why this happens, is my code wrong?
I want my connection to be established once per user and then wait for the backend to push messages
This is my error scene diagram


@AlexGuteniev - [sse] should be replaced with [server-sent-events] on questions like this, not just removed, since there is a tag for that other meaning of the acronym.  I've done that for this question.

I already know the reason, the problem has nothing to do with the front-end and back-end code, just the nginx forwarding during the request process
For SSE requests, be sure to set nginx
location /youPath {
   // Turn off proxy buffering
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_cache off;
}

Messages can be received in time only after the proxy buffer of nginx is disabled, otherwise sticky packets will be generated. When the message body is not large enough, if only part of the message is generated, it can be seen only when the timeout occurs. If there are many messages, the message size exceeds the buffer size, and sticky packets will be sent, resulting in sticky packets
